# how to know who and how predefined database service names have been used in Oracle Autonomous Transaction Processing

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle19c

According to this documentation ,
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/connect-predefined.html#GUID-9747539B-FD46-44F1-8FF8-F5AC650F15BE

Autonomous Transaction Processing provides 5 predefined database service names;

- tpurgent
- tp
- high
- medium
- low

I would like to know how these service names have been used, incuding number connections and how resources have been consumed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with some SQL statement to query V$SERVICE_STATS (you need to adapt service_name). For example:

```
SQL> select service_name, name, value
  2  from v$service_stats
  3  join v$statname
  4  on v$service_stats.stat_id = v$statname.stat_id
  5  where service_name='SYS$USERS'
  6  order by service_name, name;

SERVICE_NAME         NAME                                     VALUE
-------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------
SYS$USERS            DB time                               26317254
SYS$USERS            application wait time                      379
SYS$USERS            cluster wait time                            0
SYS$USERS            concurrency wait time                 20112125
SYS$USERS            db block changes                          1637
SYS$USERS            execute count                             7221
SYS$USERS            gc cr block receive time                     0
SYS$USERS            gc cr blocks received                        0
SYS$USERS            gc current block receive time                0
SYS$USERS            gc current blocks received                   0
SYS$USERS            logons cumulative                          108

SERVICE_NAME         NAME                                     VALUE
-------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------
SYS$USERS            opened cursors cumulative                11078
SYS$USERS            parse count (total)                       1488
SYS$USERS            parse time elapsed                    13400006
SYS$USERS            physical reads                            3643
SYS$USERS            physical writes                              0
SYS$USERS            redo size                               248932
SYS$USERS            session cursor cache hits                10309
SYS$USERS            session logical reads                    56879
SYS$USERS            user I/O wait time                    65219837
SYS$USERS            user calls                                 293
SYS$USERS            user commits                                 7

SERVICE_NAME         NAME                                     VALUE
-------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------
SYS$USERS            user rollbacks                               1
SYS$USERS            workarea executions - multipass              0
SYS$USERS            workarea executions - onepass                0
SYS$USERS            workarea executions - optimal             2557

26 rows selected.
```